# javascript url check error

Tags: javascript, url

The script receives the URL to go to that URL. 
However, `http://` will be added unless a written note.
But `http: //` There was a problem with validation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
  label {
    width : 100px;
    float : left;
    background-color:#66ccff,
    font-weight : bold;
    }
</style>
  <script>
    window.onload=init;
    function init() {
        document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = goURL;
    }
    function goURL() {

        var myurl = document.getElementById("url");
        if(myurl.indexOf('http://')==0) {
            myurl += "http://"+url;
        }
        window.open(myurl.value);
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id = "myForm">
 <label> Go to </label>
    <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="http://add url....">
    <input type="submit" value="go website">
    </form>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain `myurl += "http://"+url;` (note: `url` appears to be an undefined variable)

Comment: @AJNeufeld
If you do not include the 'http://' in the url bar, http:// beginning in the existing url (ex google.com.) including the http:// is to go to the site. result => google.com -> go

Comment: @min_jeong, what are the possibilities for a URL you are receiving as input? If the url comes back "https://..." then this code will throw an error. If you offer the possibilities we can come up with a more robust solution.

Comment: @JeremyS Even fully enter the address will not be moved.
(It has suddenly discovered).

Where can I know the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myurl = document.getElementById("url").value;
if (myurl.indexOf('http://') != 0) {
    myurl = "http://" + myurl;
}
window.open(myurl);
```

Notes:

- added `.value` after `getElementById("url")`
- `== 0` changed to `!= 0`
- `+=` has changed to `=`
- `url` has changed to `myurl`
- `window.open(myurl.value)` changed to `window.open(myurl)`

Comment: But modifications do not go to the site.

Answer (score 0):

@min_jeong, I've created a snippet for you to see some of the errors. First, you were grabbing the whole DOM element and trying to use indexOf on it. That won't work. Grab the value of the input and then check the input. Second, the += operator will add the value already there with whatever is on the right side of the argument, so you get the input + http:// + input. You only need the http:// + input. Third, if you use button type submit it will refresh the page before your javascript can run consistently, so use type="button", at least for development so you can console.log your events.

Hope this helps.

```js
function init() {
    document.getElementById("submit-btn").onclick = goURL;
}
function goURL() {

    console.log(document.getElementById("url").value);

    var myurl = document.getElementById("url").value;
    if(myurl.indexOf('http://') === -1 && myurl.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
        myurl = "http://"+myurl;
    }
    //window.open(myurl);
    //window.location.href(myurl);
  alert(myurl);
}
window.onload=init;
```

```css
label {
    width : 100px;
    float : left;
    background-color:#66ccff,
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>NEAT-O</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id = "myForm">
      <label> Go to </label>
      <input type="text" id="url" placeholder="http://add url....">
      <input id="submit-btn" type="button" value="go website">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```